# Where to submit Subsonic patch?

Tags: subsonic, patch

I just found an issue for Subsonic 2.1 that I created a patch for. Where do I go to submit that patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/list

Make sure it's still a bug in 2.2.

Edit: It's over a year later and my answer is obsolete. The google code site is no longer used although it may live on forever... Subsonic 2.2 is on [github](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0), but there is really no point in submitting a bug report for it, or trying to get a branch pull request accepted. It's a dead project.. just an observation, not a flame. There's really no community for it any more which is a shame.